# Get process by its company name

Tags: vb.net

i want to ask if it is possible to get a running process from its company name not from its name

example :

```
Dim Security() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("firefox")
    For Each proc As Process In Security
        proc.Kill()
    Next
```

in this example i get the process by its name that is firefox, but i want to get the process of firefox from " Mozilla Corporation" name

thank you in advance please provide answers with codes

Comment: Any ideas or solutions

Comment: Use the FileVersionInfo class, CompanyName property.  Process.Modules[0].FileName to get the file.  Getting this reliable is very unlikely, these strings were made for human eyes.  Very hard to see the point of this, malware is of course going to fake this and that's trivially done.

Comment: @HansPassant Could you add it as an answer ? At first glance I didn't see the comment (I found it myself in less than 5 minutes finally, but for others). More, in my case, I check this only to verify if the software is launch from one of my softwares or from outside.